# Hibernate: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im getting the following error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.project.outer.dataobject.AddressIdentificationType; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.project.outer.dataobject.AddressIdentificationType
```

After looking online for awhile now I kinda understand the error, but all the error online usually occur with a relationship between two tables (e.g. OneToMany) which need to add `@OneToMany(cascade = Cascade.ALL)` but i do not have this so i dont know what is going wrong, does anybody know?

AddressIdentificationType.js

```
Ext.apply(AddressIdentificationType, {
    valueProvider: {
        getValues: AddressIdentificationTypeService.getAddressIdentificationTypes
    },
```

AddressIdentificationType.java

```
@Entity 
@DataTransferObject(params={
    @Param(name = "match", value = "com.project.outer.dataobject.AddressIdentificationType"), 
    @Param(name = "javascript", value = "AddressIdentificationType")})
public class AddressIdentificationType extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long addressIdentificationTypeId;

@Column(length = 250, nullable=false)
private String description;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 20)
private Region region;

public AddressIdentificationType() {
}

@RemoteProperty
public Long getAddressIdentificationTypeId() {
    return addressIdentificationTypeId;
}

public void setAddressIdentificationTypeId(Long addressIdentificationTypeId) {
    this.addressIdentificationTypeId = addressIdentificationTypeId;
}

@RemoteProperty
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
protected Long getId() {
    return addressIdentificationTypeId;
}
```

AddressIdentificationTypeService.java

```
@Secured(value={"ROLE_GENERAL"})
@RemoteMethod
public List<IdentificationType> getAddressIdentificationTypes(Region region) {
    if (region == null) {
        region = Region.France;
    }
    return repository.getData(NamedQuery.AddressIdentificationTypePropertySelection, region);
}
```

If more code needs to be seen just ask to add it, just trying to keep the question as short as possible

**EDIT - Base Entity**

BaseEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Cloneable {

@Transient
private String internalUUID;

@Version
@Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
protected Integer version;

@Column(length = 50)
protected String modifiedBy;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getUUID().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o == this || (o instanceof BaseEntity && getUUID().equals(((BaseEntity) o).getUUID())));
}

private String getUUID() {

    // use the internalUUID if it has been set, otherwise create-->persist-->compare sequence will not work.
    //
    if (internalUUID != null) {
        return internalUUID;
    }

    if (getId() != null) {
        return getId().toString();
    }
    if (internalUUID == null) {
        internalUUID = randomUUID().toString();
    }
    return internalUUID;
}

protected abstract Object getId();

//protected abstract void setId(Object obj);

protected BaseEntity clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    BaseEntity object = CloneMap.get(this.getClass().getName() + ":" + this.getId());
    if (object != null) {
        return object;
    }
    BaseEntity obj = (BaseEntity)super.clone();
    obj.version = 0;

    try {
        Field field = getIdField(obj.getClass());

        if (field != null) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(obj, null);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CloneMap.put(this.getClass().getName() + ":" + this.getId(), obj);

    return obj;
}

private static Field getIdField(Class clazz) {
    try {
        String name = clazz.getName();
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(name.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + name.substring(1) + "Id");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        if (clazz.getSuperclass() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return getIdField(clazz.getSuperclass());
    }
}

private static Field getField(Class clazz, String propertyName) {
    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(propertyName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        if (clazz.getSuperclass() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return getField(clazz.getSuperclass(), propertyName);
    }
}

protected BaseEntity clone(Agent agent) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    BaseEntity obj = clone();
    try {
        Field field = getField(obj.getClass(), "agent");
        if (field != null) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(obj, agent);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}

protected <T extends BaseEntity> List<T> clone(List<T> list, Agent agent) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T e: list) {
        newList.add((T)e.clone(agent));
    }
    return newList;
}

protected <T extends BaseEntity> Set<T> clone(Set<T> list, Agent agent) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Set<T> newList = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T e: list) {
        newList.add((T)e.clone(agent));
    }
    return newList;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share your base entity with us?

Comment: Anything else that you might need?

Comment: This is interesting! ok based on a hunch can you comment out the Region field and it's accessors, try it and see if it still gives the same exception?

Comment: When I do that it gives me the error: Error in named query: AddressIdentificationTypePropertySection

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: region of: com.project.outer.dataobject.AddressIdentificationType [ from AddressIdentificationType identificationType
  where identificationType.region = ? ] .... it cant execute the query as there is cannot find a region as I took out the accessors

Comment: ok just remove the references to region for now even from queries and give it a try

Comment: when i do that i get the following error: http-8080-2 org.directwebremoting.extend.Call - No methods called class com.project.outer.service.dwr.AddressIdentificationTypeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8a9563c1.getAddressIdentificationTypes' are applicable for the passed parameters.